# Understanding the concept of wave

Tags: waves

Im learning waves, and i found this definition:

> A wave is a perturbation of matter that travels through space or in an
>   elastic environment, transporting energy without mass displacement.

I am trying to dissect each part of the definition, in order to have an understanding of it.

*Perturbation of matter*: According to what I have been reading and trying to analyze, I think this refers to: Something that modifies the "initial" state of something. Per example, the state of stillness of a pool is "disturbed", that is, it is modified, when we throw an object inside, generating waves.

I would like to know if my first analysis is correct. If so, what is the "initial" state of a vial? In the example of the water of a pool, its initial state would be the serenity or stillness of the water. But in the case of the vial, what would be its "initial" state? I think that its initial state would be to be off and the disturbance would be to turn it on, which would cause the transmission of light waves. I would like you to tell me what this "initial" state of a vial would be (assuming my analysis was correct)

In addition, I have a question in case the bulb is simply turned off. To better understand this second question, I will give an example. When you move a rope, this causes waves in it, but if you stop moving it, the waves will also stop happening. So when you turn off a light bulb, it stops transmitting waves? Or does this happen differently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While this has elements of an interesting question, I am having a hard time understanding it. You will get better answers if you can ask a specific question about waves. Also I don't understand what a vial has to do with waves.

Comment: Ask one specific question or break this up into several separate questions.  Note that the definition you found would not include E/M waves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wave is a continuous change in a physical property that varies in a periodic way over time and space. For example, water-waves are periodic changes to the surface level of the water; waves on a string are periodic changes to the position of the string from its resting position; sound waves are periodic changes in the ambient air pressure; light waves are periodic changes in electric and magnetic field strengths; gravity waves are periodic changes in the curvature of spacetime, and so on.

In your question, 'initial state' should be taken to mean the values of the physical property in the absence of the wave. So, in the case of a water wave, the initial state is the surface level of the water before it was disturbed by the wave.

Waves can be superimposed and interfere with each other. If you drop a stone into a flat surface of water you will create an expanding circular wave, which is a periodic travelling displacement of the surface level of the water. If you had dropped the stone into water that had already been disturbed by the wind, you would have created much the same wave but overlaid upon a surface level that already varied in height from place to place, so your 'initial conditions' would have been different.

I have no idea what you mean when you refer to the 'vial'.

When you turn on a light bulb it creates electromagnetic waves which radiate out from it at the speed of light. When you switch off the bulb it stops producing waves, but the waves it has already produced will continue to travel outwards until they are absorbed by something.

Comment: Note that $\delta(x-ct)$ is a wave and it is not periodic.  Ie traveling pulses are waves. Think of waves in the ocean.

Comment: Super answer, vial means light bulb according to google translate :/

Comment: So the mechanical waves are waves that need a medium, but I would like to ask you something to clarify please. The mechanical waves transfer the energy causing a particle to vibrate, then it vibrates its neighboring particle and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoOcram For your help. If you can answer this last question I would appreciate it very much since I am studying on my own. What does the shape of a wave mean? I read on a page that all waves are not really periodic since the sinusoidal form is just an idealization of real waves to facilitate their understanding. Is this true? Many thanks

Comment: In day to day life you won't meet pure sine waves, in the same way that you never meet perfect circles or perfectly straight lines, and so on. A real wave tends to have a less regular shape. The peaks of a pure sine wave are all exactly the same height and distance apart, whereas in a real wave they might vary in height and separation. However, the clever thing is that mathematically you can express an irregular wave as a superposition of pure waves. Google Fourier expansion and read-up articles about it.

Answer (score 0):

Wave describe as the transportation of energy, without actually moment of particle,where the particle vibrate and make the neighboring particle to vibrate and as vibration moved on the energy transfer is moving on.,  there are different kind of wave like pressure wave, which is formed due to rarefaction and compression, water wave, etc.